# One to One relationship lazy load not working c#

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, lazy-loading

I have this CodeFirst Entity models

```
public partial class Initial
{

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // more Properties

    [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
    [Required]
    public string CUD { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Cuenta_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Cuentas Cuenta { get; set; }
}

public partial class Cuentas
{
    public Cuentas()
    {
       //hash set for collection properties
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CUI { get; set; }

    //properties


    public virtual Initial Initial { get; set; }

    public virtual Matriz Matriz { get; set; }

}
```

`Initial` class and `Matriz` are two identical objects and any of those are loaded when I execute:

```
Cuentas account = context.CuentasCtxt.Find( 1 );
 account.Initial.Counter++;// this give a null reference because 'Initial' is not loaded
```

all the other properties are well loaded but this two, the singularity is this two entities is that they have a One-to-One relationship with `Cuentas` entity

The SQL schema looks like this[image: sql schema]

EDIT:
This is how Entity Framework Codefirst from database made the relationships

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Cuentas>()
            .HasOptional(e => e.Inicial)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Cuenta);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Cuentas>()
            .HasOptional(e => e.Matriz)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Cuenta);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Cuentas>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Movimientos)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Cuenta)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.Cuenta_Id)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

Comment: Have you enabled lazy loading? Does Lazy Loading work for other properties on the same context?

Comment: Actually was my first guess, but it was fine, to be fully sure I set the Lazy load to true in context's constructor and still not working

Comment: I added some more details about my codefirst relationships I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake, after serious hours of fustration, I found a user with the same `CUI` that hasn't assigned an `Initial` object, that's why it have a `null` value.